# Черный экран при установке Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

На компьютере уже установлена десятка, но появилась необходимость её переустановить. Устанавливаю другую сборку, которую до этого я без проблем устанавливал на другой компьютер. Но сейчас после запуска компьютера с флешки установка даже не начинается, а, уже долгое время, черный экран. Параметры компьютера и ничего такого не пишу, т.к. мой вопрос, в пределах нормы ли моя проблема? Есть ли смысл просто подождать или что-то не так?

Comment: Нет. Смысла нет. Любишь сборки - страдай. Тут нет никого кто будет думать почему зверьдвд от Васяна почему-то не работает на железе, которое ты писать не собираешься.

Comment: Так дело-то не в сборках. Была попытка и лицуху поставить - результат аналогичный.

Comment: Ну а чем писал, какая версия винды, какое железо? Телепаты в отпуске.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего ты неправильно загружаешься в флешку\установку, у некоторых компуктеров можно выбрать `uefi:флешку` или просто `флешку`.

Либо неправильно записал образ на юсб, ибо существуют разные запускаторы оси: uefi биос

Обычно я использую [руфус](https://rufus.ie/) и `Windows 10.0.18363.418 Version 1909.iso`

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте :) Решение проблемы для Вас еще актуально ? Если да, то во первых какой программой пользовались для записи винды на флэшку ? Возможно сама запись была НЕ корректной, попробуйте через Rufus , если юзали UltraISO ( например ) правильная запись - самый важный шаг и всегда в режиме NTFS , еще обращайте внимание , на то какой режим на этом компьютере в биосе включен для жесткого диска , как правило, это один из возможных конфликтов . Но все же, надеюсь Вы решили свою проблему :)

Comment: с нтфс ты не прав